# for loop conditional statement not having an effect

Tags: javascript, arrays

Edit: I can't delete the question, but there is nothing to see here I was apparently in need of a nap or more caffeine since this question makes no sense whatsoever.

I want to compare two numbers one number is the current scroll position. The other numbers are stored in an array.

However when using a for loop my conditional is not respected:

```
for (const [index, val] of arr.entries()) {
  if ( num < val ) {
    curr = index;
    console.log("num: " + num + " val: " + val);
  }
}
```

This code log out:

```
num: 0 val: 1037
num: 0 val: 1575
num: 0 val: 2532
num: 0 val: 3541
num: 0 val: 4186
num: 0 val: 5335
num: 0 val: 6376
num: 0 val: 11022
```

I would expect it to only log out the num when lower than val. However every val is being logged. Do you know why this conditional statement does not have an effect?

Comment: What is `arr` here? Please post the full code related to this.

Comment: If num is always zero, then it *is* lower than val... Not sure what the issue is here?

Comment: What is `num`? (It appears to always be `0`, so the logging makes sense.) What are the contents of `arr`?

Comment: The log does exactly what you expected it to do, what is the issue here?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't think `0` is less than `1037`, or any of the other numbers?

Comment: Sorry guys, I must have been tired.. I was trying to set num to be equal to the index of the closest value, obviously this code is not going to do that. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

Watch carefully your results:

```
num: 0 val: 1037 // Num < val!
num: 0 val: 1575 // Num < val!
num: 0 val: 2532 // Num < val!
num: 0 val: 3541 // Num < val!
num: 0 val: 4186 // Num < val!
num: 0 val: 5335 // Num < val!
num: 0 val: 6376 // Num < val!
num: 0 val: 11022 // Num < val!
```

Your condition works fine, maybe there is a misunderstanding ?

Comment: "Your condition works as expected" is an incomplete answer given the actual question "Why my condition does not work". It looks clearer to me if original log formatted with comments and hightlights are included. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161224/discussion-between-mose-raguzzini-and-mhodges).

Answer (score 0):

If `num` is always zero, then it is lower than `val` - the conditional appears to be operating as expected.

Comment: It is. And also an answer that answers the question - not sure what your problem is?